# Grails framework: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: grails, groovy

When I tried to assign the value to the variable "newDBName", I got the error:

```
ERROR [grails.app.controllers] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: DataSourceConfigService.$() is applicable for 
argument types: DataSourceConfigService$_injectNewDatasource_closure1_closure3) 
values: [DataSourceConfigService$_injectNewDatasource_closure1_closure3@1e1ae104]
```

Code:

```
class DataSourceConfigService {

def injectNewDatasource() {
            String newDBName = ""
            Environment.list().each {env ->
                if( !grailsApplication.mainContext.containsBean( "${env.accountName}" ) ) {

                            def bb = new BeanBuilder()
                            bb.beans {
                                  "${env.accountName}"(ComboPooledDataSource) {bean -> ...}
                                  bb.registerBeans( grailsApplication.mainContext );
                            }
                            log.info "Added bean called ${env.accountName}"

                            newDBName = ${env.accountName}
                }
            }
            return newDBName
}

}
```

Here's how I call the function:

```
String newDBName = dataSourceConfigService.injectNewDatasource()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes on the `newDBName` assignment line.  Either use

```
newDBName = "${env.accountName}"
```

or just skip the conversion to GString (it looks unnecessary based on this snippet at least) and use

```
newDBName = env.accountName
```

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you!